# Limiting the amount of RAM an application can use

Tags: windows-7, memory-management

I am looking for a program that can limit the amount of RAM an application is allowed to use. If possible, free and compatible with Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 5):

Process Lasso provides some advanced process monitoring options:

http://www.bitsum.com/processlasso/index.php

You can configure rules inside a process watchdog that triggers an action (e.g. terminating the process) when the memory usuage becomes greater than defined.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Watchdog configuration]

> You can also disallow specified processes from running, log all
>   processes run, and even set various other process rules. These rules,
>   amongst many others, include automatically restarting or terminating a
>   process after it reaches some CPU or memory threshold

Comment: Nice one, thanks! It seems like memory limitation isn't free, right? http://www.bitsum.com/howfree.php

Comment: So excellent!!! But why "restart the proccess"? Why not to "cut virtual memory"?